# jquery get previous column class in separate row

Tags: jquery, html-table, row

I have a table similar to this (I've created a simpler example here):

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="4" class="topic">Topic Name</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><a href="#">link</a></td>
    <td><a href="#">link</a></td>
    <td><a href="#">link</a></td>
    <td><a href="#">link</a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><a href="#">link</a></td>
    <td><a href="#">link</a></td>
    <td><a href="#">hello world</a></td>
    <td><a href="#">link</a></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

This is an example table with three rows and four columns.  What jQuery code do I use to get the text() in the first td with the class "topic" calling from the td with the text "hello world"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `closest` to traverse up through the DOM

```
$("td").on("click", function(){
    $(this).closest("table").find("td.topic").first().text()
});
```

Comment: The downvote is strange indeed as your solution works: http://jsfiddle.net/YzXn7/ +1 for working solution.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('table td').on('eventName', function(){
    var topic = $(this).closest('tr')
                       .prevAll('tr:has(td.topic)')
                       .first()
                       .text();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7Y5fN/

Comment: I actually have many class "topic" cells so this answer worked for me - THANKS!!